# Mac OSX IPTables equivavlent

Tags: iptables, mac-osx, mac

Just wondering how I would accomplish the following IPtables rules under Mac OSX:

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t mangle -p udp --sport 7078 -J TOS --set-tos Maximize-Reliability
iptables -A PREROUTING -t mangle -p udp --sport 7078 -J TOS --set-tos Maximize-Throughput
iptables -A PREROUTING -t mangle -p udp --sport 7078 -J TOS --set-tos Mimimize-Delay
```

Also, with the source-port (sport), is that freely interchangeable with the destination port (dport)?

Many Thanks in advance.

Tobias

Answer (score 2):

You want the '`ipfw`' command.

Comment: ipfw is now deprecated and replaced with pfctl, but otherwise correct.

Comment: well, it seems none of them have ability to update TOS byte

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have to redirect some UDP traffic to external IP addresses. 
Running Mac OSX 10.9 (Mavericks) with PF. ipfw was deprecated. But anyway, PF is running on the old syntax pre 4.7 I guess. You might want to tweak ips and interfaces.

```
ext_if="en0" 
int_if="bridge100"
old_ip="1.2.3.4"
new_ip="5.6.7.8"
rdr pass on {$ext_if, $int_if} inet proto udp from any to $old_ip -> $new_ip
```